# Getting error installing virtualenvwrapper and distutils

Tags: python3

I am trying to install virtualenv but getting the below error on ubuntu bionic

```
rock64@rockpro64:~$ pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig
```

'
But if i try install distutils i get different error:

```
rock64@rockpro64:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/222 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,143 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 120131 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/Grammar.txt', which is also in package python3.8-lib2to3 3.8.0-1+bionic2
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/README', which is also in package python3.8-distutils 3.8.0-1+bionic2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Your post shows you are attempting to install `python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb` but it seems to be conflicting with the installed `python3.8-distutils 3.8.0-1+bionic2`.  Is your Python 3.8 install from an unofficial repository?  Did you happen to use the Deadsnakes PPA which has a [change from last week that addresses this very problem](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/10718949/+listing-archive-extra)?  If not, please tell us where your Python 3.8 came from and if the official Ubuntu Python 3.8 works any better.

Comment: After installing ubuntu i was installing python 3.8 following unofficial repository you are guessing following this link https://vsupalov.com/developing-with-python3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this change log notice for the latest revision of their Python 3.8 release](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/10718949/+listing-archive-extra), the maintainers of the Deadsnakes PPA acknowledged that their release conflicts with upstream Ubuntu.

First update `python3.8` to the newest release or remove it entirely.  You want to ensure the removal of the `python3.8-distutils`, `python3.8-tk`, `python3.8-gdbm`, `python3.8-lib2to3` packages, after which you should no longer be conflicting with Ubuntu packages.

You should then be able to install `python3-distutils` from the official Ubuntu repositories, which should fix the `virtualenv` issue you are experiencing.